# Symbolic vs. numeric error codes in web API

Tags: php, api, exception, error-code

I'm currently working on new project, which should provide a web-based API. Of course, there are many cases, when requested operation fails and API should report about reasons of this fail.

Previously I used traditional way, when response contains numeric error code and more human-friendly error message, but maintaining error code list and mapping between my codes and internal exceptions was a bit frustrating.

I thought that it might be more convenient to use symbolic error codes, for example generated from exception names.

I see following advantages of this idea:

- No need for mapping from exceptions to numbers.
- Impossible to assign same error codes to different error types (in my case - exceptions).
- Error code becomes more informative for developer who will use API by itself.

And disadvantages:

- Exposing exception names might be not so good idea in terms of encapsulation.
- Since error codes are mostly used by API client applications to determine error type, comparing string is more expensive.
- No need for central exception->errcode registry increases chances to miss some of error codes in documentation.

So, what is better to use: symbolic or numeric error codes?

Comment: Why not use PHP defines , e.g. "define('EXCEPTION_INVALID_SOMETHING', 42);" in a file holding just these defines? That way the user sees just the numbers and the developer knows where the error came from.

Comment: This is exactly what a meant under numeric approach. But maintaining error code list in a separate file was the thing that was bugging me.