# API response: difference between string and numeric type

Tags: json, api, rest, object, types

I have an API used by a mobile app. It has an endpoint named **/feed**

It returns a collection of objects with different types.

```
[
    {
        "type": "USER",
        "value": 5632,
    },
    {
        "type": "IMAGE",
        "value": 1412,
    },
]
```

I am wondering, whether the type should be a **string** or a **number** like this:

```
[
    {
        "type": 100,
        "value": 5632,
    },
    {
        "type": 200,
        "value": 1412,
    },
]
```

Is there a significant difference between the two? The IOS developer of the app stated that numbers are easier to compare than strings.

Found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775812/symbolic-vs-numeric-error-codes-in-web-api) but it does not have any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, numbers are faster to compare than strings, that's a fact. Then, whether it is a significant gain or not will depend on the algorithm where this json is parsed, the quantity of data it contains, etc. And furthermore, sacrificing code design for performances is often a bad option. It really depends on your project.

Comment: I see, so it still depends on the way they parse it. What do you think should be a recommended approach?

Comment: @kapitanluffy: The odds of it mattering *at all* are exceedingly low. Instead, consider other factors, like usability, how easy they each are to debug, etc.